# ID of object with all of its variables in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

With this class, I want this class's ID to be the value of all of its attributes. This implicitly means that I need only row with these values existing in the database. How to do this in Hibernate?

```
public class WeatherState {
    private String weatherType;
    private double temperature;
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your asking, can you re-word your question or provide an example of what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When persistent attributes should be directly attributes of WeatherState, then [@IdClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html) is way to go (persistence annotations are imported from javax.persistence package):

```
@Entity
@IdClass(WeatherStateId.class)
public class WeatherState {
    @Id private String weatherType;
    @Id private double temperature;
    //getters, setters
}

public class WeatherStateId implements Serializable {
    private String weatherType;
    private double temperature;
    //getters, setters, equals, hashcode
}
```

Other options is to use [@EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html):

```
@Entity
public class WeatherState {
    @EmbeddedId private WeatherStateId weatherStateId;

    public WeatherStateId getWeatherStateId() {
        return weatherStateId;
    }

    public void setWeatherStateId(WeatherStateId weatherStateId) {
        this.weatherStateId = weatherStateId;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class WeatherStateId implements Serializable {
    private String weatherType;
    private double temperature;
    //getters, setters, equals, hashcode
}
```

In both cases it is important to provide equals and hashcode, as said in JPA 2.0 specification:

> The primary key class must define equals and hashCode methods. The
>   semantics of value equality for these methods must be consistent with
>   the database equality for the database types to which the key is
>   mapped.